# PLW-07204: conversion away from column type may result in sub-optimal query plan how to handle it

Tags: sql, plsql, warnings

create or replace procedure EMP_TEST(V_STARTDATE varchar2)
as
LV_CNT number;

begin
select COUNT(*) into LV_CNT from EMP
where to_char(JOIN_DATE,'YYYYMM')

end;

Comment: First, please add a tag for the language (sql?).  Second, explain what you're doing, what happens, and what's wrong with it.

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!